# array_search return wrong key

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$ar = [ 'key1'=>'John', 'key2'=>0, 'key3'=>'Mary' ];
```

and, if I write:

```
$idx = array_search ('Mary',$ar);
echo $idx;
```

I get:

```
key2
```

I have searched over the net and this is not isolate problem. It seems that when an associative array contains a 0 value, array_search fails if strict parameter is not set.

There are also more than one [bug warnings](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65844), all rejected with motivation: “array_search() does a loose comparison by default”.

Ok, I resolve my little problem using strict parameter...

But my question is: there is a decent, valid reason why in loose comparison `'Mary'==0` or [`'two'==0`](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/141vp9f59k/php-bug-bug-66583-new-array-search-always-returns-0-for-string-elements-for-a-mixed-type-array) or it is only another php madness?

Comment: I think it stop search when got first equals. If put `key3` before `key2` (`$ar = [ 'key1'=>'John', 'key3'=>'Mary', 'key2'=>0];`) `array_search` will return `key3`.

Comment: As said in the [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) manual... You need to set the 3th parameter if the search needs to be strict...

Comment: @Naruto Yes, I write it in my question. My question is about 'why?', not 'how'...

Comment: @LVAmeda  because int of any string is equal to zero

Comment: Strict comparison is not using == it's using === ... That's basically the point of strict..

Comment: @splash58 that is the answer, I think... Thank you!

Comment: @Naruto yes, Naruto, I well know. My point was another... :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to set **third parameter** as `true` to use strict comparison. Please have a look at below explanation:

`array_search` is using  `==` to compare values during search

FORM PHP DOC

> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the array_search() function will search for identical elements in the haystack. This means it will also check the types of the needle in the haystack, and objects must be the same instance.

Becasue the second element is `0` the string was converted to `0` during search

Simple Test

```
var_dump("Mary" == 0); //true
var_dump("Mary" === 0); //false
```

Solution use `strict` option to search identical values

```
$key = array_search("Mary", $ar,true);
                                  ^---- Strict Option
var_dump($key);
```

**Output**

```
string(4) "key3"
```

Comment: excellent explanation ....

Comment: life saver .... :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a 0 (zero) numeric value in array, and `array_search()` perform non-strict comparison (==) by default. `0 == 'Mary'` is true, you should pass 3rd parameter to `array_search()` (true).

Answer (score -1):

You just chnage in your array in `'key2'=>'0'`  you not give single or double quotation

```
$ar = [ 'key1'=>'John', 'key2'=>'0', 'key3'=>'Mary' ];
```

this is working fine

Comment: You are actually converting the integer to string which is a wrong approach.

Answer (score -1):

```
  $ar = [ 'key1'=>'John', 'key2'=>'0', 'key3'=>'Mary' ];
```

Comment: You are actually converting the integer to string which is a wrong approach.